# Data frame does not display column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, databricks

I wrote a script which first runs a SQL query to get the data from Redshift (via Databricks). Then, I want to display it in a pandas data frame. The problem is that somehow the names of the columns were removes/are not displayed. Why?

```
#SQL Query
query = """
SELECT * FROM table1 limit 1;  
"""

# Execute the query
try:
  cursor.execute(query)
except OperationalError as msg: 
  print ("Command skipped: ")

#Fetch all rows from the result
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Convert into a Pandas Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] )

df.head()
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, the column names turned into numbers (in yellow). The intent was to display column name 1: Customer_id, column name 2: Purchases, column name 3: Product_id etc.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: use `pd.read_sql()`

Comment: You did not pass column names to pd.DataFrame so pandas assigned default column names which start from 0

Comment: @Vaishali oh, great catch, how would I pass those?

Comment: pd.DataFrame( [[ij for ij in i] for i in rows] , columns = [...])

Comment: @Vaishali In the brackets [], i do not want to manually enter as there are 100+ column names. How does it automatically fetch it all?

Comment: In that case, you should try read_sql

Comment: pd.read_sql() worked magic! thanks

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Chris you can use `pd.read_sql` in the following way:-

```
query = """SELECT * FROM table1 limit 1;"""

connection = psycopg2.connect(user = 'your_username',
                                    password = 'password',
                                    host = 'host_ip',
                                    port = 5432,
                                    database = 'db_name')

data = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=connection)
```

Now when you will print your `data` it will show the column names as well!

Comment: I am using sql.connect() from mysql-connector driver instead of psycopg2.connect().